# Growth rate of the functions

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to order functions according to their growth rate but I am stuck here.
y=5^{n} , y=(n!)^{n} , y=(n^{2})!

5^{n} is exponential I am assume this is bigger but I cannot proof that. When looking at their graphs it seems like (n^{2})! is bigger I cannot understand.
Help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the logarithms. This will tel you work with the much more manageable functions (keep in mind the Stirling approximation `log(n!) ~= n * log(n)`):

```
n * log(5)
n * log(n!) ~= n^2 * log(n)
n^2 * log(n^2) = 2 n^2 * log(n)
```

Can you continue?

Comment: I didnt know the Stirling approximation thank you. I think I got the point y=5^{n} is the smallest but in algorithm analysis we didn't care contants so can we say that y=(n!)^{n} and y=(n^{2})! have same growth rate ?

Comment: No. Their _logarithms_ have the same order. The logarithms of `f = n^2` and `g = n^3` have the same order, but the functions themselves have the different orders. Be careful with constants.